# How do I Prevent Someone Uploading APKs of My App

Tags: java, android, apk

I discovered that some unauthorized actor is downloading my app from the Google Play store and somehow creating APKs of it. They are uploaded to websites like apkcombo and the like. How do I prevent this?

From the research I have done, obfuscating the code sounds like it might help but is this enough to prevent the app from being cloned?

Update:

I discovered that there is no way to prevent someone from copying/uploading the apk itself, but you can prevent the clone from working using the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to verify if your app has been downloaded from an authorized source or not .

You can use for example Google's License Verification Library, it manages a connection between your app and the Android Market